# An error 'A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed' occurs while accessing ServiceLifetime.Scoped DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I've got a strange issue in my WebApi service. Once in a while it throws an exception while trying to read the data from Postgres Db

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext.
For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
```

There is plenty of info regarding this case but all of the articles deal with DbContext being registered with incorrect ServiceLifetime. But the DbContext that I'm using has been registered as Scoped (I've inspected the serviceCollection's registrations) using AddDbContextPool extension method, so it shouldn't throw such an error. Another important point: this issue sometimes occurs in Production but I wasn't able to reproduce it locally.

So, I would greatly appreciate help regarding the following questions

1. How come I still get this exception if DbContexts have been regitered as Scoped?
2. Am I right assuming that DbContext registered with ServiceLifetime.Scoped should not cause such an error? Or do I need to create scopes explicitly (e.g. via ServiceScopeFactory)?

Bonus questions
3) Are there any ways to reproduce this issue locally (specifically with AddDbContextPool extension usage)? I'd like to reproduce it because this way I will able to confirm that my fix works, otherwise I'll need to deploy these fixes to PDN and try them there.
4) Obviously, switching from `AddDbContextPool` to something like

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(contextOptions =>
            contextOptions.UseNpgsql(connStr, npgOptions =>
            {
                ...
            }), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

is likely to solve the issue but this approach will cause performance drop. I was wondering if anyone knows how big this drop is going to be? Maybe someone has made this specific comparison (Pool vs Non-Pool)

Comment: `Am I right assuming that DbContext registered with ServiceLifetime.Scoped should not cause such an error?` No, not necessarily.

Comment: Are you using `Task.Run` or threads and accessing the database from there?

Comment: Usually this error appear when you forgot to put `await` in some place.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv you are right, but I've already double-checked it and all awaits are in place

Comment: @mjwills 1. I use async-awaits to get the data from Db, no explicit `Task.Run` or `System.Thread` usage. The concurrency issue kicks in due to multiple service calls.

Comment: @mjwills "Am I right assuming that DbContext registered with ServiceLifetime.Scoped should not cause such an error? No, not necessarily. " --- please tell me more about such case(s), maybe this is the issue that I've ran into

Comment: So, ensure that the same context not used in different tasks. `DbContext` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You are right, that's where the trouble occurs. But my DbContext is registered as Scoped which theoretically guarantees that an instance of DbContext is created per scope... and for some unknown reason I still have this issue

Comment: Scoped means that you have to create scope in each Task. For Controller call ASP.NET automatically creates scope.

Comment: `please tell me more about such case(s),` Check the second and third comments. They are the usual two causes (also see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913 - the link in your error message). We can't help further without a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you run into same problem or not, but the problem can be in your controller, at least that was my case,

It occurs to me when I try to perform multiple crud operations ( lets say, I am in a `HttpPost` method but inside it i am executing both `create` and `delete` )

So use this code in between curds ( I did `create` then `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear();` then `delete`)

```
        _context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```

`_context` refers to the current context you are using to perform crud ( like `context.Remove` or `context.Add`)

Comment: This might be the case, however, the core question here is: why do we have this issue in a first place, if DbContext has been registered as Scoped?

Comment: In his specific case he is calling the methods from within one request, as far as I know scoped makes a DbContext per request so Scoped would not help you here iirc.